# Can I insert an animate inside another animate function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to create a slide effect using jquery. I want my images to have some text above them, which should fade out, then slide the image, then fade back in.

I was wondering if I can use an animate function inside another animate function, like this:

```
$('.slider-content').animate({
            'opacity':'0'
        },4000, function{
            $('.slider-list').animate({
            // fade("out");
            'margin-left' : "+=" + left_indent
        },4000,function(){
            if(where == 'left') {  
                $('.slider-list li:first').before($('.slider-list li:last'));
            } else {
                $('.slider-list li:last').after($('.slider-list li:first'));
            }
                $('.slider-list').css({'margin-left' : '0px'});
                fade("in");
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm sorry if this question sounds stupid, but this came up while I was brainstorming for ideas. Is it possible?

The current code gives me an error on the third line, it says unexpected '}'.

Comment: That's a basic syntax error.. you should write `function(){` not `function{`.

Comment: _Is it possible?_....here the question is `->` did you tried it??

Comment: @MjrKusanagi Thanks, I can't believe I was so sloppy.

Comment: Yes I have, otherwise how would I know what error it gives me? It's my code, but I am really new to javascript and this flexibility is a thing to get accustomed with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function should have parenthesis:

```
},4000, function(){
```